# Sitecore Habitat Installation issue

Tags: habitat, installation

I tried to install Habitat and followed all the instructions mentioned at:
https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started

When I run the default task as mentioned in step 5 of wiki, I keep on getting the following error (i have already executed npm install and npm install -g gulp-cli):

> [10:44:53] Starting '03-Publish-All-Projects'... [10:44:53] Starting
>   'Build-Solution'... [10:44:53] { Error: spawn C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild. exe ENOENT
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)   code: 'ENOENT',   errno: 'ENOENT',   syscall: 'spawn C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.ex e',   path: 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe',   spawnargs:
>   [ 'C:\Projects\Habitat\Habitat.sln',
>        '/target:Clean;Build',
>        '/verbosity:minimal',
>        '/toolsversion:15.0',
>        '/nologo',
>        '/maxcpucount',
>        '/nodeReuse:False',
>        '/property:Configuration=Debug',
>        '/property:Platform=Any CPU' ] } [10:44:53] MSBuild failed! [10:44:53] 'Build-Solution' errored after 36 ms [10:44:53] Error:
>   spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.ex e
>   ENOENT
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9) [10:44:53] 'default' errored after 2.12 s [10:44:53] Error in plugin
>   'run-sequence(Build-Solution)' Message:
>       spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ENOENT Details:
>       code: ENOENT
>       errno: ENOENT
>       syscall: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
>       path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
>       spawnargs: C:\Projects\Habitat\Habitat.sln,/target:Clean;Build,/verbosity:mi
>   nimal,/toolsversion:15.0,/nologo,/maxcpucount,/nodeReuse:False,/property:Configu
>   ration=Debug,/property:Platform=Any CPU Stack: Error: spawn C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9) [10:44:53] '03-Publish-All-Projects' errored after 49 ms [10:44:53]
>   Error in plugin 'run-sequence(default)' Message:
>       spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ENOENT Details:
>       code: ENOENT
>       errno: ENOENT
>       syscall: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
>       path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
>       spawnargs: C:\Projects\Habitat\Habitat.sln,/target:Clean;Build,/verbosity:mi
>   nimal,/toolsversion:15.0,/nologo,/maxcpucount,/nodeReuse:False,/property:Configu
>   ration=Debug,/property:Platform=Any CPU Stack: Error: spawn C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9) [10:44:53] '03-Publish-All-Projects' errored after 58 ms [10:44:53]
>   Error in plugin 'run-sequence(Build-Solution)' Message:
>       spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ENOENT Details:
>       code: ENOENT
>       errno: ENOENT
>       syscall: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
>       path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
>       spawnargs: C:\Projects\Habitat\Habitat.sln,/target:Clean;Build,/verbosity:mi
>   nimal,/toolsversion:15.0,/nologo,/maxcpucount,/nodeReuse:False,/property:Configu
>   ration=Debug,/property:Platform=Any CPU Stack: Error: spawn C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

Any suggetions to fix the error?

Thanks in advance.

Nicks

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have?

Comment: Have you installed nodejs in your computer?

Comment: The default Habitat repo has major dependencies on Node, NPM, Gulp and other tooling that is very problematic for developers. If you just want the site locally, and have a TDS license, I'd suggest using the TDS fork and just doing Deploy Solution. https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat/tree/TDS-latest.
It simplifies it. Note: this is a comment, not an answer, as I know it doesn't resolve your specific build problem....but it resolves mine! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The newest update from Habitat is using MSBuild v15 which is included in VS 2017. Hence, you should install VS2017 or use the way from @peaks. There is also the alternative way is change the configuration in gulp-config.js by v14 instead of v15 in case you are using VS2015.

[image]

Comment: i was also facing the same issue, but now fixed after changing buildtoolversion from 15.0 to 14.0

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting build error as 'Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild. exe ENOENT ' ensure you set the buildToolVersion: auto.

[image]

I was able to determine this 'auto' value, looking at the logic on the gulp-msbuild\lib\msbuild-finder.js

You can find more details in the below blog link.

https://sivalingaamorthy.wordpress.com/2018/09/17/error-spawn-cprogram-files-x86msbuild15-0binamd64msbuild-exe-enoent/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: In Visual Studio, open Tools > Options > Web Package Management > In "Locations of external tools", move the $(PATH) to the top (before .\node_modules.bin).

[image]

Now, in Task Runner Explorer, try running the **default** task.

Comment: Thanks for the update but even after implementing the suggested changes I am still getting the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Check if you have the latest NodeJS version installed in your computer. 2. Delete the folder node_modules and then run `npm install` again

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct build tools installed (Gulp is expecting MSBuild 15).

This is a separate download to VS2017 - look for **Build Tools for VS2017** here: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/